# What are the expected fields of setAdapter method on a ListView?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

So I'm trying to build a Navigation drawer. When I try to run `setAdapter` on my `ListView` object, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to pass in the second field.

> drawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,?,drawerItems));

I referred the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) but their code is

> mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
>                   R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));

And they haven't explained the `drawer_list_item` layout or what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an `R.layout` resource integer built from a `drawer_list_item.xml` file that describes how to load the view.

And the documentation does explain it.

> The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

By default, the objects in the adapter will be loaded into the ListView from their toString method into a Textview with `@android:id/text1`

The simplest layout is `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: So is the layout being used here supposed to have a `TextView` element?
If yes what should be it's contents?

Comment: Here's the built in layout that I referenced at the bottom.  You can use it as written for that parameter, you don't need to write your own XML https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

Comment: Thanks I got it. :)